NX not resolving modular config
I'm using @nx/rollup for my NX package with Rollup. When running the build command with the verbose flag I get an error:
Failed to process project graph. Run "nx reset" to fix this. Please report the issue if you keep seeing it.
  AggregateCreateNodesError: An error occurred while processing files for the @nx/rollup/plugin plugin.
    - packages/etech-ui-utils/rollup.config.mjs: Cannot find module '/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/@nx/rollup/with-nx' imported from /Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/packages/etech-ui-utils/rollup.config.mjs
  Did you mean to import @nx+rollup@19.4.1_@babel+core@7.24.7_@babel+traverse@7.24.7_@swc-node+register@1.9.2_@swc+cor_fgicgqlkk4ny7xdovezuby7riq/node_modules/@nx/rollup/with-nx.js?
      at createNodesFromFiles (/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.4.1_@swc-node+register@1.4.2_@swc+core@1.5.29_@swc+helpers@0.5.11__@swc+types@0.1.9__@s_eiy6zms5xooatzr5625sihijqq/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/plugins/utils.js:58:15)
      at async LoadedNxPlugin.createNodes.<computed> (/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.4.1_@swc-node+register@1.4.2_@swc+core@1.5.29_@swc+helpers@0.5.11__@swc+types@0.1.9__@s_eiy6zms5xooatzr5625sihijqq/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/plugins/internal-api.js:41:28)
      at async Promise.all (index 1)
      at async processFilesAndCreateAndSerializeProjectGraph (/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.4.1_@swc-node+register@1.4.2_@swc+core@1.5.29_@swc+helpers@0.5.11__@swc+types@0.1.9__@s_eiy6zms5xooatzr5625sihijqq/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/project-graph-incremental-recomputation.js:148:43)
      at async getCachedSerializedProjectGraphPromise (/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.4.1_@swc-node+register@1.4.2_@swc+core@1.5.29_@swc+helpers@0.5.11__@swc+types@0.1.9__@s_eiy6zms5xooatzr5625sihijqq/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/project-graph-incremental-recomputation.js:46:16)
      at async handleRequestProjectGraph (/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.4.1_@swc-node+register@1.4.2_@swc+core@1.5.29_@swc+helpers@0.5.11__@swc+types@0.1.9__@s_eiy6zms5xooatzr5625sihijqq/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/handle-request-project-graph.js:12:24)
      at async handleResult (/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.4.1_@swc-node+register@1.4.2_@swc+core@1.5.29_@swc+helpers@0.5.11__@swc+types@0.1.9__@s_eiy6zms5xooatzr5625sihijqq/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/server.js:139:16)
      at async handleMessage (/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.4.1_@swc-node+register@1.4.2_@swc+core@1.5.29_@swc+helpers@0.5.11__@swc+types@0.1.9__@s_eiy6zms5xooatzr5625sihijqq/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/server.js:92:9)
      at async /Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.4.1_@swc-node+register@1.4.2_@swc+core@1.5.29_@swc+helpers@0.5.11__@swc+types@0.1.9__@s_eiy6zms5xooatzr5625sihijqq/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/server.js:58:9

The error recommend using a .mjs file extension or setting your package.json file; I've tried both.
Here is my root package.json:
{
  "name": "@etech-ui/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {},
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nx/js": "19.4.1",
    "@nx/rollup": "19.4.1",
    "@nx/workspace": "19.4.1",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.9.1",
    "@swc/cli": "~0.3.12",
    "@swc/core": "~1.5.7",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.11",
    "@types/node": "18.16.9",
    "nx": "19.4.1",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "rollup": "^4.14.0",
    "swc-loader": "0.1.15",
    "tslib": "^2.6.3",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2",
    "verdaccio": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "nx": {
    "includedScripts": []
  }
}

Project structure:
├── nx.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   └── etech-ui-utils
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── project.json
│       ├── rollup.config.js
│       └── src
│           ├── index.ts
│           └── lib
│               └── etech-ui-utils.ts
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
├── project.json
├── tsconfig.base.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.lib.json

I've tried downgrading @swc-node/register as recommended in this similar GitHub issue but no luck here.
